# Выборка mySQL с N-ой записи таблицы до лимита

Tags: mysql

Есть задача начать выборку с n-ой записи таблицы до лимита. К примеру после n-ой нужно выбрать 10 записей, как составить такой запрос?

Comment: Вам уже советовали: перед тем как задавать вопросы, вы бы хоть немного поразбирались в предметной области. Это основы, без знания этих основ нет смысла лезть куда-либо.

Прочитайте хотя бы что-нить типа "MySQL за 21 день" - тогда такие вопросы не будут вас ставить в тупик.

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT n, 10 - выбрать 10 записей начиная с n-ной.

Comment: А можете на примере написать запрос?

Comment: добавьте это в самый конец Вашего запроса.

    select * from mytable limit 20,10

Comment: А почему 20,10? єто что с 20 записи до 10 будет идти выборка?

Comment: это с 20 записи взять 10 штук. Первое поле это offset (смещение), второе - row_count (количество записей).

Можно ещё и так написать

    LIMIT 10  OFFSET 20